# Calculate the sum of minutes in overlapping timeranges

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to calculate the sum of minutes of terms. Overlapping terms should not count multiple times.

```
Declare @Terms table (Start DATETIME, Finish DATETIME)
INSERT INTO @Terms values
    ('2016-8-3 08:00','2016-8-3 09:00'),
    ('2016-8-3 09:00','2016-8-3 10:00'),
    ('2016-8-3 08:00','2016-8-3 09:30'),   -- overlapping term
    ('2016-8-3 11:00','2016-8-3 12:00')
```

The result from the data above should be 180 minutes (3 hours). What is the easiest and fastest way to to this?

Comment: Have you attempted anything at all?

Comment: @dfundako No, i seriously need a hint. Of course you could try to extract overlapping terms, but there are multiple ways of overlapping, witch makes this complicated.

Comment: Look up gaps and islands. This is a classic islands situation.

Comment: We believe in you.

Comment: I've worked on this before, it can be tough.  When you say 'overlapping' do you mean any intersection between the times in two records?  Because records can intersect in many different ways, such as one contained in another, one starts before other ends - and after that you get the third time period that overlaps an overlap, then some but not all of the rest of the periods.  For that reason, I showed a method I contemplated with a CTE table of all minutes, then count the minutes intersecting  >1 periods.  That is potentially very costly to the system, so we ended up using code, not SQL

Comment: @brenkdar - sorry I see you mentioned the 'multiple overlap' problem, so you know that looking for matching start and end times doesn't get you there - try my WITH statement though, it may be ok for limited periods of time, e.g. one day

Comment: @brenkdar - your overlap is 8:00 to 9:30 - but you do want to count that as 180 mins?  So you do want to count time in both periods, but not any third period?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With the help of a cross apply.

```
Declare @Terms table (Start DATETIME, Finish DATETIME)
INSERT INTO @Terms values
    ('2016-8-3 08:00','2016-8-3 09:00'),
    ('2016-8-3 09:00','2016-8-3 10:00'),
    ('2016-8-3 08:00','2016-8-3 09:30'),   -- overlapping term
    ('2016-8-3 11:00','2016-8-3 12:00')

Select Minutes = sum(Minutes)
 From (
        Select Distinct 
               B.DateR1
              ,B.DateR2
              ,Minutes = DateDiff(Minute,B.DateR1,B.DateR2)
         From @Terms A
         Cross Apply (
                      Select DateR1=Min(Start)
                            ,DateR2=max(Finish) 
                       From  @Terms 
                       Where Start <= A.Finish and Finish >= A.Start
                     ) B
 ) A
```

Returns

```
Minutes
180
```

The sub-query returns

```
DateR1                     DateR2                   Minutes
2016-08-03 08:00:00.000    2016-08-03 10:00:00.000  120
2016-08-03 11:00:00.000    2016-08-03 12:00:00.000  60
```

Comment: what does 11:00 to 12:00 overlap with?  Unless I misinterpreted it, which I have, because I see the answer to be 90

Comment: @AndrewDeighton the 11 - 12 stand alone. Only the 1st 3 rows in this case overlap thus the Distinct DateR1,DateR2

Comment: @AndrewDeighton I should add the Cross Apply generate the Min/Max ranges

Comment: @AndrewDeighton Edited my answer to make the SQL more readable

Comment: thanks for that, I worked on something similar once, I'm not sure what he meant by some of his points, but he's apparently deleted the whole question!

Comment: Nice solution. I would only touch the where part to get overlaps (cosmetic I think) : Where Start <= A.Finish and Finish >= A.Start

Comment: @CetinBasoz You are correct, and I updated my answer.  I just visualize it as BETWEEN

Comment: Tnx for the solution. Works well. Only problem could be performance with a large number of terms. Because this way are compared to each other.

Comment: @brenkdar A wise man once told me "One test is worth a thousand expert opintions".   I would love to know how it performs on a real-world data-set.  Cheers

Comment: @JohnCappelletti There might be a problem if a range is entirely encompassed by another range.  Replace the 9:30 with 8:30 in the overlapping range and this returns 240 instead of the expected 180.

Comment: @Progone Huh, I'll take a harder look in a bit.  Thanks for the notice.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26796228/6168731 appears to cover this case, but the usual warnings of UTC only and things get funky with local times and DST.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform a `LEAD` function, which falls under window statements, to find overlap.  I created a table called `TIME_TEST` and inserted your values, when I sum the difference it returns three hours.[Lead Function Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125.aspx)

```
SELECT SUM(PREV_TIME - END_TIME) FROM (
SELECT *, LEAD(END_TIME) OVER(ORDER BY START_TIME) PREV_TIME
FROM TIME_TEST
ORDER BY 1
)FOO
;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @MAX as datetime;

SELECT @MAX = MAX(finish) FROM TERMS;

;WITH MINS AS (SELECT MIN(Start) N FROM TERMS
                UNION ALL
                SELECT dateadd(mi, 1, N) FROM MINS WHERE N < @MAX),
      OVERLAPMINS AS (
                        SELECT Mins.N from MINS 
                                            JOIN Terms T 
                                                    ON   T.Start <= MINS.N AND MINS.N < T.Finish 
                                                        GROUP BY Mins.N 
                                                            HAVING COUNT(0) > 1
                        )
      SELECT COUNT(0) totalmins FROM OVERLAPMINS 
option(maxrecursion 0)
```

except I get 90, how do you make it 3 hours if overlapping terms do not count multiple times?  You seems to have counted your overlaps twice though.  What if there is a third time period that overlaps at various times with 1 and 2 other periods?  Are you saying that overlapping periods are counted twice always (that is ok since any overlap has >=2 periods overlapping in any minute) so you could just multiply my count by 2

```
...SELECT 2 * COUNT(0) totalmins..
```

if you want to count an overlap as 2, but no more