# SQL - Total Time on day

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

My table looks a lot like the table shown in the following StackOverflow URL:
[Calculating total time excluding overlapped time & breaks in SQLServer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26782860/calculating-total-time-excluding-overlapped-time-breaks-in-sqlserver)

My table also includes an OwnerID. Each person has an unique OwnerID, and I could easily join in the person name belonging to that ID.

The result requested should be just like in the linked URL, but per Owner. I tried modifying the selected answer for his URL but that gives me the following error:

```
The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.
```

This is the query I try to run...

```
 ;WITH addNR AS ( -- Add row numbers

SELECT StartDate, EndDate, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY StartDate, EndDate) AS RowID
FROM dbo.FollowUp AS T
WHERE StartDate > '2017-10-02 08:30:00.000'
), createNewTable AS ( -- Recreate table according overlap time

SELECT StartDate, EndDate, RowID 
FROM addNR
WHERE RowID = 1

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN a.StartDate <= AN.StartDate AND AN.StartDate <= a.EndDate THEN a.StartDate 
        ELSE AN.StartDate END AS StartTime, 
    CASE WHEN a.StartDate <= AN.EndDate AND AN.EndDate <= a.EndDate THEN a.EndDate 
        ELSE AN.EndDate END AS EndTime,
    AN.RowID 
FROM addNR AS AN
INNER JOIN createNewTable AS a
    ON a.RowID + 1 = AN.RowID

), getMinutes AS ( -- Get difference in minutes
SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE,StartDate,MAX(EndDate)) AS diffMinutes
FROM createNewTable
GROUP BY StartDate
)
SELECT SUM(diffMinutes) AS Result
FROM getMinutes
```

Where I replaced StartTime=StartDate and EndTime=EndDate since my columns are named so..

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEGRK.png)

Comment: You should include sample data at least; we should not have to sift through another question to figure out yours.

Comment: Depending upon your SQL Server Version (tag hint) you could eliminate the recursive CTE using LEAD or LAG

Comment: I included some sample data. You can now see the 2nd row is overlapping the first row in time and I don't this data in my final result. The total time should be 15.30-7=8.5 hours. And not 8.5 hours and 5 minutes.

Comment: I am pretty sure that you would get the right answer quickly if you would prepare SQL scripts to create all the objects with the data and then provide expected result. You can use sqlfiddle.com for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coincidence @vitalygolub .

Try my script with various sample data.Also Time Calendar table should be permanent table so it is only time creation.

It is not Recursive so it should perform better.If output is thrown then distinct can be avoided.

```
    create table #tbl (ownerid int,StartTime datetime,enddate datetime);
insert into #tbl values
 (1,'2014-10-01 10:30:00.000','2014-10-01 12:00:00.000') -- 90 mins
,(1,'2014-10-01 10:40:00.000','2014-10-01 12:00:00.000') --  0 since its overlapped with     previous
,(1,'2014-10-01 10:42:00.000','2014-10-01 12:20:00.000') -- 20 mins excluding overlapped time
,(1,'2014-10-01 10:40:00.000','2014-10-01 13:00:00.000') -- 40 mins
,(1,'2014-10-01 10:44:00.000','2014-10-01 12:21:00.000') -- 0 previous ones have already covered this time range
,(1,'2014-10-13 15:50:00.000','2014-10-13 16:00:00.000') -- 10 mins

create table #Timetable(timecol time primary key  )
insert into #Timetable
select   dateadd(minute,(c.rn-1),'00:00')
from(
select top (24*60)  row_number()over(order by number)rn from 
master..spt_values order by number)c


SELECT c.ownerid
    ,cast(c.StartTime AS DATE)
    ,count(DISTINCT timecol) TimeMin
FROM #Timetable t
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT *
    FROM #tbl c
    WHERE timecol >= cast(c.StartTime AS TIME)
        AND timecol < cast(c.enddate AS TIME)
    ) c
GROUP BY c.ownerid
    ,cast(c.StartTime AS DATE)


drop table #Timetable
drop table #tbl
```

Comment: Cool, this seems to be working! However, I would like to split them by each date. The result considering your values would be:

ID:1 Date:2014-10-01 TimeMin:150
ID:1 Date:2014-10-13 TimeMin:10

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is working code, am not sure about performance. The idea: create "calendar" with 1 minute precision, fill it for every OwnerId and calculate number of records

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (OwnerId int,StartTime DateTime2, EndTime DateTime2)

INSERT INTO @table SELECT 1,'2014-10-01 10:30:00.000', '2014-10-01 12:00:00.000'
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 1,'2014-10-01 10:40:00.000', '2014-10-01 12:00:00.000'
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 1,'2014-10-01 10:42:00.000', '2014-10-01 12:20:00.000'
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 1,'2014-10-01 10:40:00.000', '2014-10-01 13:00:00.000'
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 1,'2014-10-01 10:44:00.000', '2014-10-01 12:21:00.000'
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 1,'2014-10-13 15:50:00.000', '2014-10-13 16:00:00.000'
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 2,'2014-10-01 10:30:00.000', '2014-10-01 12:00:00.000'
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 2,'2014-10-01 10:40:00.000', '2014-10-01 12:00:00.000'
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 2,'2014-10-01 10:42:00.000', '2014-10-01 12:20:00.000'



declare @period int, @start datetime;;
select @period=datediff(mi, MIN(starttime),MAX(endtime)),@start =MIN(StartTime) from @table;


declare @seconds table(num int identity(0,1),garbage bit not null);
insert into @seconds(garbage) values(0);
while( select COUNT(*) from @seconds) < @period
    insert into @seconds(garbage ) select garbage  from @seconds;

with a(ownerId, usedminute ) as 
(
    select distinct t.ownerID,s.num from @seconds s join @table t on   
    dateadd(mi,s.num, @start) between t.StartTime  and dateadd(s,-1,t.EndTime)
)
select ownerId, count(*) time_in_minutes from a group by ownerID;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without `while` loops using a derived tally table and regular set based joins, which as a result will perform very efficiently:

```
-- Define test data
declare @table table (ownerid int,starttime datetime2, endtime datetime2);

insert into @table select 1,'2014-10-01 10:30:00.000', '2014-10-01 12:00:00.000';
insert into @table select 1,'2014-10-01 10:40:00.000', '2014-10-01 12:00:00.000';
insert into @table select 1,'2014-10-01 10:42:00.000', '2014-10-01 12:20:00.000';
insert into @table select 1,'2014-10-01 10:40:00.000', '2014-10-01 13:00:00.000';
insert into @table select 1,'2014-10-01 10:44:00.000', '2014-10-01 12:21:00.000';
insert into @table select 1,'2014-10-13 15:50:00.000', '2014-10-13 16:00:00.000';
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
insert into @table select 2,'2014-10-01 10:30:00.000', '2014-10-01 12:00:00.000';
insert into @table select 2,'2014-10-01 10:40:00.000', '2014-10-01 12:00:00.000';
insert into @table select 2,'2014-10-01 10:42:00.000', '2014-10-01 12:20:00.000';

-- Query

declare @MinStartTime datetime;
declare @Minutes int;

-- Define data boundaries

select @MinStartTime = min(starttime)
      ,@Minutes = datediff(minute,min(starttime), max(endtime))+1
from @table;
                  -- Initial Numbers Table - 10 rows
with t(t)     as (select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1)
                  -- Create tally table of minutes by cross joining numbers table many times to generate 1m rows
    ,n(n)     as (select top(@Minutes) dateadd(minute,row_number() over (order by (select null))-1,@MinStartTime) from t t1, t t2, t t3, t t4, t t5, t t6)
                  -- Define largest possible range for each OwnerID
    ,o(i,s,e) as (select ownerid, min(starttime), max(endtime) from @table group by ownerid)
select o.i as OwnerID
      ,cast(n.n as date) as DateValue
      ,count(n.n) as TotalMinutes
from o
    join n        -- Return minutes for each OwnerID range,
        on n.n between o.s and o.e
where exists(select null            -- where that minute should be included.
             from @table as t
             where n.n >= t.starttime
               and n.n < t.endtime)
group by o.i
        ,cast(n.n as date)
order by o.i
        ,DateValue
```

Output:

```
+---------+------------+--------------+
| OwnerID | DateValue  | TotalMinutes |
+---------+------------+--------------+
|       1 | 2014-10-01 |          150 |
|       1 | 2014-10-13 |           10 |
|       2 | 2014-10-01 |          111 |
+---------+------------+--------------+
```